# How to Change View to 100% in HTML Object

Tags: html, flash, size

i have a swf File which has the Size 3840 x 800px.
Now i want to put it in a html file.

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%"
        codebase="http://active.macromedia.com/flash7/cabs/ swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0">
        <param name="movie" value="wand.swf" />
        <param name="play" value="true" />
        <param name="loop" value="true" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
        <PARAM NAME="SCALE" VALUE="default" />
        <embed src="wand.swf" width="100%" height="100%" SCALE="default" play="true" loop="true" quality="high"
            wmode="opaque" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash">
</embed>
    </object>
```

In HTML it zooms the File and dont show 100% of the File. How can i deactivate Show All and activate 100%?

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/809/gitter.png/

On the Left Side is the 100% View... on the right the "Show All" View.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what the problem is, but i do now that its not funny in any way to deal with the object tag. And I'm trying to stay away from it as much as i can.
Try to embedd your swffile i with [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) instead its really easy to use and they even got a htmlgenerator to help you with the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the "scale" param to "noScale". That should prevent the zooming in. Make sure the containing element your object is in has a width and height of 100% as well. I would also suggest, as Tjelle did, using swfObject to embed your file instead of old object /embed tags.